# Pg Admin 4 no me esta mostrando todas las filas

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

tengo un problema con PG Admin 4 versión 4.21, lo que pasa es que al momento de ejecutar mi query me manda el mensaje que 9000 filas han sido afectadas, lo cual me tiene que devolver este numero de filas en el Data Output
[image: Problema de filas]

Pero al momento de irme al Data Output y copiar las filas solamente me esta copiando 1000 filas y de igual manera si utilizo el scroll para irme al ultimo registro me muestra solamente hasta el 1000, ¿alguna sugerencia de como solucionarlo y que me copie las 9000 filas?

Comment: Por favor comparte el Query, de esa manera tu pregunta sera mejor recibida

Comment: select rfc, sum(total_importe)
from chcp
where (quincena between '201801' and '201824' )
group by rfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes una limitante en la configuración del archivo `config.py` ubicado en la ruta `pgAdmin4/web folder`.

La variable `ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT` viene configurada en 1000, debes cambiar este valor por el que necesites.

Este es un ejemplo de la sección del archivo que debes modificar:

```
 ##########################################################################
 # Number of records to fetch in one batch in query tool when query result
 # set is large.
 ##########################################################################
 ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT = 1000
```

En este [enlace](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html) consigues la documentación oficial de este y cada parametro del archivo `config.py`

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias me ayudaste a resolver este problema en el cual me llevaba matando buscando solución, te agradezco muchisimo.